# pip: Missing distribution spec. How to fix this?

Tags: python, pip

I am getting following error while running this command on my virtual machine:

```
$ sudo pip install -U -v --no-deps -b /tmp/piyush/ /tmp/piyush/common_bundle

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2807, in parse_requirements
    raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '/tmp/piyush/common_bundle')
```

My input file is an archive.

```
$ file common_bundle
common_bundle: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

The version of pip is:

```
$ pip -V
pip 6.0.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Here is the pip manifest present in the common_bundle:

```
# This is a pip bundle file, that contains many source packages
# that can be installed as a group.  You can install this like:
#     pip this_file.zip
# The rest of the file contains a list of all the packages included:
PyYAML==3.10
boto==2.6.0
msgpack-python==0.2.2
tornado==2.1.1
ujson==1.22
virtualenv==1.8.2
bottle==0.10.7
raven==2.0.3
protobuf==2.4.1
# These packages were installed to satisfy the above requirements:
simplejson==2.4.0
distribute==0.6.32
```

Does anything look fishy?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the bundle have a `requirements.txt` with a malformed line?

Comment: @musically_ut: No. I looked into that file and it looks good. I also fired the command "pip install -r file.txt" and it went through successfully. I updated the pip manifest file above.

Comment: Why are you passing `--no-deps`?  That seems like a great way to get a broken installation...

Answer (score 0):

When `pip` installing from an archive, the file must either have the proper extension or you need to explicitly use the `file://` protocol. Rename your file to `/tmp/piyush/common_bundle.zip` or use `file:///tmp/piyush/common_bundle`.

The error you're seeing has nothing to do with the contents of the archive, `pip` hasn't even unpacked it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are any spaces in your path. This was my problem. Also try keeping the path to the file as short as possible.